# How to change the created and last modified date of a file to present time in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am looking for a command in bash to change the last modified and created timestamp to be changed to present time.
How do I do it using shell command/script?

Thanks!

Comment: Unix file systems don't have a "created" timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`touch` will update the access and modification times (or only one of the two with `-a` or `-m` respectively).

Comment: can you give the command to do it for all the files in the directory for updating both created at and modified at times to current time? Thanks!

Comment: @user3667569 There is no "created at" time.

Comment: Thanks and is it possible to give only one command to change the modified for all files and folders?

Comment: I did By doing touch * for all directories manually.

Comment: touch -t 1705191234 /var/crash/server.log.2017-05-17.tar.gz
will change the file timestamp as listed in ls -l output to the date specified in the -t